# How to trap an error from a shelled process in c#

Tags: c#

ive been using this site for a while and have my first question to ask - as the help here is awesome.

Im writing a c# dll (for use in VbScript) and in that DLDL im shelling out a command and wish to trap the return code of that command. So far I have the following c# code:-

```
      public int InstallHotfix(String strAppName,string strExe,string strParam)
            {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strExe,strParam);                                         
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;                                                          
            Process.Start(startInfo);                                                                                                  
            }
```

I am calling this from a VB script but would like to know how to return the result back to VBS. I assume there a 'return' value that I have to enter but im unsure how to achieve this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strExe, strParam);
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
        proc.WaitForExit();
        int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Comment: bloomin 'eck that was quick! Ill give that a go, many thanks!

Comment: You could redirect the output streams for additional information

Comment: @Jodrell, I am currently only looking for the error number from the process but what additional information can be obtained (for future ref)?